# .net arcobjects retrieve user value from layer data source

Tags: arcobjects, layers, .net, user-account

I have a need to get the user value from a layer properties.

The value is from: Layer Properties -> Source -> user in Data Source (sorry not enough score to attach the picture).

I tried to check the ILayerProperties, but haven't found the method related to the user value.

Anybody has the experience?

Comment: What is the data source? If I load a shapefile I do not see a "user" property in the data source of layer in ArcMap.

Comment: Hi Hornbydd, the data is from ArcSDE geodatabase, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are asking for the username of a layer's SDE connection. You need to use IWorkspace and IPropertySet.  Something like this:

```
Dim pDataset As IDataset = the feature layer/raster layer you want the user name of
Dim pWorkspace As IWorkspace = pDataset.Workspace
Dim pPropertySet As IPropertySet = pWorkspace.ConnectionProperties
Dim userName As String = pPropertySet.GetProperty("USER")
```

IPropertySet essentially gives you a dictionary of the properties and their values. If you need to get all the properties or all the values you can put them into arrays:

```
Dim propertyNames() = Nothing
Dim propertyValues() = Nothing
pPropertySet.GetAllProperties(propertyNames, propertyValues)
```